# How to find the electric field of a charged tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

Let's say there is a charged tube(cylinder with no top or bottom) with radius $a$, length $l$ and charge $q$ and a point which is collinear with the centre of the charged tube. Anyway, since we can think the tube as infinite charged rings we first should calculate the electric field of a single ring.(the distance between ring and point charge is $r$ and the distance between the centre of the ring and point charge is $d$)
$$
dE= (k.dq)/r^2
$$
where $dq$ is infinitesimal charge.
$$
dE_x=(k.dq)/r^2cos(\theta)
$$
$$
dE_x=(k.d.dq)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)}
$$
$$
E_x=∫(k.d.dq)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)} =(k.d)/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)}∫dq=kdq/(a^2+d^2)^{(3⁄2)} 
$$
Finally, we found the electric field of a single ring. However, I am stuck at how to integrate the equation to find the total electric field of the charged tube. How should I integrate it?

P.S: It may seem like the [other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131831/how-to-calculate-the-electrostatic-force-between-two-dielectric-rings-of-charge) I asked but they are different in concept of what the question is.

Comment: As a hint, consider what $dq$ is in terms of the given geometric quantities. If the cylinder is uniformly charged, what can we say about its charge density?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/904954/11127